# ListView Not Displaying Added Text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0

### Background:

Hello everyone, I'm not new to visual basic or programming. I just find it the fastest to make a GUI in visual basic for various programs; however, I'm having a recent issue.

I have a form with a ListView control that I populate using a textbox and a button.

the code I use for the button is:

### Code:

```
listview1.items.add(textbox2.text)
```

Pretty simple code that has always worked. I changed a few properties on my ListView as well, and I will list them. I just don't know what is going on.Here's a list of the properties changed (everything else is default):

### Properties:

```
BackColor = DarkGray
BorderStyle = FixedSingle
HeaderStyle = None
MultiSelect = False
View = Details
```

All properties were changed via the *properties* tab and not through code. I want to be able to add text to the control. I'm not adding any subitems either. I'm just confused because this code has always worked, and I've never had this issue. I'm also using **Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition** if that helps.

Comment: "`I just find it the fastest to make a GUI in visual basic`". Are you tracking an IP Address? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDD03yeLnU

Comment: LOL, I love it. But nah, in my years of networking, Wireshark would be my buddy for packet sniffing. @Joel Coehoom

Comment: for Details View, you must have added a column for the items/subitems to display

Comment: So I can add a column, and still have it hidden and it should still work?

Comment: OK, that works. I guess I didn't think of the logic behind it. Simple blind mistake. Thanks @Plutonix

Comment: columnheaders dont have a Visible property

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

If the added item in `ListView` is not displaying then check the **`ListView.View`** property. if this property has set to **`Detail`** view then Columns must be added in that listView control otherwise added item will not display.

Make sure item is added correctly.

```
Dim item As ListViewItem = listView1.Items.Add("Item Text")  ' This text will be displayed in first column. The column index will be 0
' Further values will be added in SubItem
item.SubItems.Add("Sub Item1")
item.SubItems.Add("Sub Item2")
item.SubItems.Add("Sub Item3")
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what isn't supported.  I've edited your answer to put the `'` in.